# Z-Index Not Working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, z-index

Hey everyone, I'm a bit confused as to why the Z-index for an element isn't working as expected on a webpage I'm working on. I'm trying to create a pseudo-drop shadow effect using a jQuery plugin in Internet Explorer (so far, only tested in IE8, but will need to work in IE7 as well). My problem is, the shadow is being positioned correctly for my main header, but it's showing above the actual text, instead of below. I've tried explicity declaring each Z-index, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Any idea how to get this shadow below the header? Thanks!

[link](http://www.savagefreelance.com/fuel_tank/)

Comment: Can you post HTML you are using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to enter the link, I've updated now

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to work in IE7, but NOT IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided instead to use a different method, as detailed here: http://stansight.com/WordPress/2007/10/28/text-drop-shadows/

This seems to work better for the most part, with some adjustments.